# Get error Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, sip

Trying to connect Raspberry Pi ZERO to asterisk

May some one know where is problem, have already prepared Asterisk external

Have Raspberry Pi ZERO

**Step by step:**

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

---

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential automake autoconf libtool libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libssl-dev libsamplerate0-dev libcommoncpp2-dev libccrtp-dev libzrtpcpp-dev libdbus-1-dev libdbus-c++-dev libyaml-dev libpcre3-dev libgsm1-dev libspeex-dev libspeexdsp-dev libcelt-dev
```

---

```
mkdir pjsip
cd pjsip
svn checkout http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk
cd trunck
```

---

---

```
cp ./user.mak.sample ./user.mak
nano ./user.mak
```

---

Change first line to:

```
export CFLAGS += -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard
```

---

```
nano ./aconfigure
```

---

8885 line need to change from

```
*win32* | *w32* | *darwin* | *linux*)
ac_webrtc_instset=sse2
*)
```

---

---

to:

```
    case $target in
        *arm*)
            ac_webrtc_instset=neon
            ;;
        *)
            ac_webrtc_instset=sse2
            ;;
    esac
    ;;
*)
```

---

```
./configure && make dep && make clean && make
sudo make install
```

---

additional changed before third_party/build/os-auto.mak.in

---

created conf file to connect to the Asterisk (my.conf)

---

emulate the mic input

```
sudo modprobe snd-dummy
```

---

Then i run:

```
pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --config-file my.conf --playback-dev -0 --capture-dev -1
```

---

Then i get error^ but i don't know how to fix it, may be it's because Raspberry pi ZERO not have the mini jack 3.5?

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

---

full log:

```
22:52:07.715 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.9-svn for POSIX initialized
22:52:07.725 sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
22:52:07.732          pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0xd8e380)
22:52:07.734 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" registered
22:52:07.741 sip_transport.  .Transport manager created.
22:52:07.743   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> CREATED
22:52:07.745 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
22:52:07.749 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
22:52:07.750 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
22:52:07.751 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered
22:52:07.753 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered
22:52:07.754 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" registered
22:52:07.756 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

**Thank's for any help or ideas!**

Comment: maybe something in [this pjsip issue](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/issues/2448) will help

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for this problem^ may be help some one**
https://community.asterisk.org/t/pjsip-get-error-cannot-connect-to-server-socket-err-no-such-file-or-directory-on-raspberry-pi/87576